# Nhibernate QueryOver WithSubquery

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, nested, queryover

I have a detached query that projects 2 fields:

```
var detached = session.QueryOver.Of<ClassA>().
       select
       (
         Projections1.....X
         Projections2.....Y
       )

var result = session.QueryOver<ClassB>()
       .WithSubquery
       .WhereProperty(p => p.X)
       .In(detached)
       .List();
```

What i would like to do is this:

```
select * from tableA a
       where (a.x, a.y) in (select x, y from tableB b)
```

What i want is to have two fields in the nested part, but how am I adding two fields in my WhereProperty ??

Comment: I don't think you could do this in straight up SQL could you? If you can't, it's certainly not possible with QueryOver.

Comment: The select, I have written above, is perfectly valid

Comment: yes but not the in parten because QueryOver can not produce `(a.x, a.y) in ...`

Comment: Both QueryOver and ICriteria should be able to group on fields without automatically projects the fields. Sometimes you may want to group on a field and pick the newest among the found entities in the group. This is not possible and it is so annoying